# Possible to change SIM card PUK on Android device?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, settings, security, sim-card, sim-unlocking

On my Samsung Galaxy SIII, one can go to `Settings -> More -> Security -> SIM card lock -> Set up SIM card lock -> Change SIM PIN` to change the default PIN that came with the SIM card. But what about the PUK (the 8-digit number that comes with the SIM card to unlock the card after 3 failed 4-digit PIN number attempts)? Can the PUK also be changed from within the Android GUI, or is it a fixed number stored on the SIM card which cannot be changed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The PUC (PUK) is a SIM-specific code assigned by the service provider.
>   - [Personal Unblocking Code (Wikipedia)](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personal_unblocking_code)

That means you cannot change it with help of your android device.

If you want to crack it you must watch [this video](http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=wBzb-Zx4rsI)


Video is about 'Rooting The Sim' by  Karsten Nohl at BlackHat 2013.

In this video Nohl showed vulnerability that almost every sim have  which was manufactured before 2013(Also Some cards after that whoes providers have not fixed this security hole)

**Procedure**
-Send binary sms with OTA command to card requesting response

-Crack DES signing key that sign Java virus and sent through binary sms

-Leverage gaps in Java VM memory separation to access arbitrary sim card data

**Results**
-Card may response with DES signed error message

-Card install and execute signed Java applet

-Malicious applet extract ki,banking applet etc. and send ti attacker via sms

*Once an attacker cracks the key, he can commit premium SMS fraud, circumvent caller-ID checks, manipulate voice-mails, redirect incoming calls and text messages, abuse USSD payments, track and phish users, install malware on their devices, or perform any other browser-based attack. With data access enabled, Nohl claims an attacker can clone SIM cards, decrypt 2G, 3G, and 4G traffic, clone NFC takers and future SIM applications, and alter the operating system to prevent future patching.*

**Nohl also claims to have been able to break out of the SIMs Java sandbox and get access to this personal unblocking key**

Comment: I guess it's a read-only piece of information on the SIM card.

Comment: PUC stands for Personal Unlock Code, whereas PUK stands for Personal Unlock Key. Both terms refer to the same thing.

Comment: Yes. They both are synonymous. If you want to change it you have to contact your service provider and ask for PUK. If you can prove that you are owner of sim they can give you the PUK.

Comment: Thank you @{Ash-Ishh..} (not sure how to encode your Twitter handle) for your information. I was wondering whether the PUK is stored on a read-only area of the SIM or whether, upon providing due credentials, the service provider can also change the PUK, or whether it can only be retrieved. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent talk! I was impressed by the fact that network operators can communicate with SIM cards (in mobile phones that are powered on) without the smartphone user being able to even turn such communication on or off. Perhaps Android phones should come with this option. Was also impressed to find out that the SIM card has a built-in sandboxed Java environment running on one of several custom OSs built into the card by SIM card manufacturers. Hearing about all those vulnerabilities, which allow malicious users to break into SIM cards (but not the Android OS), was also interesting.

Comment: What I didn't understand about the talk is, how does a hacker send data to a SIM card. Wouldn't the hacker have to use a base-station, such as those installed across cities by network operators, to send data to cell phones to try to hack into them? Anyways, really interesting talk!

Comment: In this talk (@22:40) he mentioned that binary sms can also be sent through some phones (he used specific reprogrammed motorola device)

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that, the Motorola device he had must be something wonderful for hackers to have to experiment with. Anyways, I thought putting the device in Airplane Mode would cut off all communication to the device, including binary SMS messages sent by the network operator, but what the speaker in the talk said is true, this is not the case. I guess I will be turning my phone completely off while in airplanes from now on. Thanks.

Comment: As a minor update, I would like to add that upon logging in to the network operator's website with my phone number and password I was also able to view my PUK on such website.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is an older thread, but to provide useful into to others reading the page now I thought I'd still reply.

This doesn't always work with every phone, but if it doesn't work it wouldn't cause any harm. It also requires that you know what the current PUK number is. This can often be found on the credit card size card that your SIM card came attached to (if you still have it) or it can usually be obtained from your wireless provider fairly easily so long as you can verify that it is your account.

All you have to do is dial this code into your phone replacing "old PUK" with the PUK provided by your wireless provider, and "new PUK" with any 8-digit code of your choosing. Note you don't use any spaces when you enter the code.

** 05 * old PUK * new PUK * new PUK #

Comment: I believe this answer is misleading. It should be "new PIN" rather than "new PUK". Hence that dial code is used for changing PIN instead of changing PUK.

Answer (score 0):

You should write new pin new pin, there is no way to change puk code. Your topic explains how to make blocked pin code active.